# Axios POST request data appearing as undefined

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, express, axios

I am using React, NodeJS and Express for this. I am using a form such that once the form is submitted, a function is called that sends the data to the back-end. A proxy has been set up in the react package.
This is the code in the React App:

```
import React from "react";
import { useState } from "react";
const axios = require('axios');

const Target = () => {
    const [Val, setVal] = useState('');

    const sendVal = (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        axios.post('/api', {
            TGVAL:Val
        })
        .then(function (response) {
            console.log(response);
        })
    }

    return(
        <div className="TargetPrice">
            <form onSubmit={sendVal}>
                <label htmlFor="inputTarget">At what value do you want the alert?</label>
                <br />
                <input type="text" className="inputTarget" value={Val} onChange={(e) => setVal(e.target.value)} />
                <button style={{marginLeft:"5px"}} type="submit">Submit</button>
            </form>
        </div>
    )
}
export default Target;
```

And here is the back-end code:

```
const express = require("express");
const PORT = process.env.PORT || 3001;
const app = express();

app.post('/api', (request, response) => {
  console.log(request.TGVAL);
})
```

Whenever the form is submitted, 'undefined' is logged in the back-end.

I know that some data is being received by the backend because each time the form is submitted, it logs undefined. Problem is that it isn't logging the data from the form.

Any help on this would be appreciated.

EDIT: Problem has been solved thanks to Jaromonda X. Added `app.use(express.json())` and `request.body.TGVAL`

Comment: do you have body parser middleware (add on or the express "built in") configured - e.g. `app.use(express.json())` - then the incoming data is on `request.body.TGVAL`

Comment: I don’t see you’re updating your state.